# Printing contents of DefaultTreeModel

Tags: java, swing

I am using 
 `javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode` and  `javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel` for creating nodes and the tree itself.

How do I know print the contents of the entire tree? I need to do an `BFS` traversal.

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: hmmm... I think you would rather need to do a dfs traversal

Comment: print as System.out.println() or print to paper output

Answer (score 1):

Reading the api doc helps :-)

DefaultMutableTreeNode has traversal methods, a [recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918356/jtree-how-to-get-the-text-of-all-items) has a simple code snippet which uses it to print out the nodes with indentation.